# Why TPL Dataflow block.LinkTo does not give any output?

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I am quite new to the topic TPL Dataflow. In the book *Concurrency in C#* I tested the following example. I can't figure out why there's no output which should be `2*2-2=2`;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Task tt = test();
    Task tt = test1(); 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static async Task test1()
{
    try
    {
        var multiplyBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>(item =>
        {
            if (item == 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Blech.");
            return item * 2;
        });
        var subtractBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>(item => item - 2);
        multiplyBlock.LinkTo(subtractBlock,
        new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        multiplyBlock.Post(2);
        await subtractBlock.Completion;
        int temp = subtractBlock.Receive();
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        // The exception is caught here.
        foreach (var v in e.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.Message);
        }

    }

}
```

Update1: I tried another example. Still I did not use `Block.Complete()` but I thought when the first block's completed, the result is passed into the second block automatically.

```
private static async Task test3()
{
    TransformManyBlock<int, int> tmb = new TransformManyBlock<int, int>((i) => { return new int[] {i, i + 1}; });
    ActionBlock<int> ab = new ActionBlock<int>((i) => Console.WriteLine(i));

    tmb.LinkTo(ab);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        tmb.Post(i);
    }
    //tmb.Complete();
    await ab.Completion;
    Console.WriteLine("Finished post");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part of the code:

```
await subtractBlock.Completion;
int temp = subtractBlock.Receive();
```

is first (asynchronously) waiting for the subtraction block to complete, and then attempting to retrieve an output from the block.

There are two problems: the source block is never completed, and the code is attempting to retrieve output from a completed block. Once a block has completed, it will not produce any more data.

(I assume you're referring to the example in recipe 4.2, which will post `1`, causing the exception, which completes the block in a faulted state).

So, you can fix this test by completing the source block (and the completion will propagate along the link to the `subtractBlock` automatically), and by reading the output before (asynchronously) waiting for `subtractBlock` to complete:

```
multiplyBlock.Complete();
int temp = subtractBlock.Receive();
await subtractBlock.Completion;
```

Comment: I do not quite get the part `completing the source block (and the completion will propagate along the link to the subtractBlock automatically`! I post an update which did not use `tmb.Complete()` method but I did see all the output.

Comment: @baozi: "Completion" for a block means that it is completely done - it will never send any more data. So the data flows through it to its target blocks *until* it completes. Once it's complete, there's no more data.

Comment: Can I say for two linked block, it can receive data from the second block only if the first block is called to `Complete`

Comment: @baozi: If block A is linked to B, which is linked to C, then data can flow all the way through. Complete is not at all like a "flush"; it's more of a "dispose".

Comment: This is not a correct solution when using Receive, when you post a value of 1 which causes an exception, there is no AggregateException but InvalidOperationException -> the InvalidOperationException does not hold the exception that was thrown.